# Can I export a MySQL schema to latex?

Tags: mysql, documentation

I have asked this question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4328612/199217) before, but did not get a good answer.

I would like to be able to export a MySQL schema to a set of Latex tables.

phpMyAdmin does this, but it is buggy and does not export table comments in LaTeX.

Are there other linux-compatable, open-source options?

Answer (score 1):

[EMS Data Export for MySQL](http://www.rsoftr.com/business/databases-tools/ems_data_export_for_mysql-28697.html)

When I search "MySQL Export Latex" dozens of links leads to this product.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I had not considered this software because it proprietary software that requires a microsoft operating system. I have changed my question accordingly.